# PHP ssh2_shell execute command and get response

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, libssh2

I am connecting to an ssh server and using `ssh2_shell` to create an interactive `bash` shell.

The problem I have is how to send a command to the shell and get the response for the command accurately.

This is what I am currently doing:

```
$stream = ssh2_connect();
$shell = ssh2_shell($stream, 'bash');

fwrite($shell, "whoami\n");
fwrite(STDOUT, fread($shell, 2048) . PHP_EOL);
```

The problem with the above code is the output to `STDOUT` (for commandline view) shows something like `Last login to server etc..` aka the welcome message. I have to wait a second or two and then read from the shell again to get the output of the command I sent.

Now I can solve this by doing `sleep(1)` after any command I send but this is very hacky. If the command takes longer than a second, I will not get the results. If the command takes less than a second, I waste time.

I tried `stream_set_blocking($shell, true)` before writing the command and calling `fread` but the problem still persists unless I sleep after the command.

Basically, how can I use ssh2_shell, send a command and get the response for that command regardless of how long it will take, without timing out the script by requesting content of a blocked stream after the shell has returned its contents?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the intended behavior of ssh2_shell - it is interactive. That means you would need to work with timeouts.

If you want a command or script executed on the remote host and just receive its output you need non-interactive execution - ssh2_exec.